# MY mouse cursor is being freezed while work on ssms

Tags: installation, ssms, ssms-2012

I have a strange situation. i have installed SSMS on my laptop and it runs well the first time, connected to server but after few times, the mouse cursor being freezed while work or execute the query over ssms 2012. i have reinstalled the ssms 2012 but still face same issue.

Can you please help me out from strange situation.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why, but I strongly recommend you to install standalone SSMS 2016 that has some good new features like live query statistics and monthly updates. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx